# tel link android not working (Galaxy S5)

Tags: android, cordova

I'm new to mobile hybrid app development. I have a HTML 5 hybrid app developed in Angular and Ionic where in part of the application i want to launch the native phone app (or a menu of various ways to get to the native phone app) when a user clicks on a phone number. When i view the hybrid app through a browser in my phone, clicking on the links works as expected. However, if i deploy the application  to my Samsung Galaxy S5 (via cordova), tapping the links does nothing. 
I've tried the following syntaxes:

```
<a href="tel:18888888">tel:18888888</a>
<a href="tel:+18888888">tel:+18888888</a>
<a href="tel://18888888">tel://18888888</a>
<a href="tel://+18888888">tel://+18888888</a>
<a href="tel:1-888-8888">tel:1-888-8888</a>
<a href="tel://1-888-8888">tel:1-888-8888</a>
```

I'm using Cordova 3.6.0 and the Android SDK r23.0.2 windows.

I've googled similar issues but the results are inconsistent.

Has anyone had any luck with this? Seems like a common feature. I must be missing something simple.

Comment: SOLVED! Cordova 3.6.0 introduces a second whitelist, for restricting which URLs are allowed to launch external applications. Cordova 3.6.0 Whitelist Guide So you need to add explicitly in the config.xml: <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" /> <access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" /> This answer was from a post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745096/android-phonegap-how-to-open-native-google-maps-application

Comment: I missed the solution first then came back to the same page with different search keywords on google ;p .. you get a thumbs up !!

Comment: You can answer your question @RobertTaylor by the way i have posted now :)

Answer (score 21):

You should add this line in config.xml to let the app lunch an external app:
`<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />`

Answer (score 15):

As Commented above:

Cordova 3.6.0 introduces a second whitelist, for restricting which URLs are allowed to launch external applications. Cordova 3.6.0 Whitelist Guide So you need to add explicitly in the config.xml:

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" /> 
<access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745096/android-phonegap-how-to-open-native-google-maps-application).

Thanks