# Making Phone Call Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, frameworks, hybrid

I'm using this code in the view:

`<a href="tel:{{doc.emergency}}" class="button phone button-full" >Phone Call</a>`

And I can't make the call. 
This is my **config.xml**

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the following works:

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
```

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432413/tel-link-android-not-working-galaxy-s5).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the native plugin:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number/

You can create a function that receive the phone number as a parameter.