# AngularJS ng-href tel doesn't work on nexus 9 (Android 5.1)

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, nexus

I have a **Call button** in my mobile app (AngularJS, Ionic).
The button works fine on *IOS* and *some Android phones*, It displays the **Dial call Interface**. 
 
But when I tested it on ***Nexus 9 (Android 5.1)***, It doesn't show the dial call but it suggest me to add the number to **the contact list**.

Do you have any idea why it's not working on the nexus ? Thanks :)

This is my code :

In the view : 
`<a ng-href="tel:{{ phone_number }}> Call <a>`

In Config.xml : 
  `<access launch-external="true" origin="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432413/tel-link-android-not-working-galaxy-s5

Comment: No, It's not the same question, in my case, the app works on all phones but the nexus !