# Why Launching Native Google Maps Application from Cordova shows Antartica?

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, geolocation

[following this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745096/android-phonegap-how-to-open-native-google-maps-application) and working with Corodva 3.6 bring me to open the Native google maps from my app. That's what I wanted.

Here is the exact line I'm executing:

```
window.location.href = url;
```

Where url is equal to:

```
geo:-122.41327719999998,37.7715108
```

It does open the map. But it brings me to Antartica with geo:0,0 I think.

What am I doing wrong ?
I did use `<access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />` in my config.xml

Many thanks

Comment: it seems cords `-122.41327719999998,37.7715108` are invalid, try with some others.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have -122 for latitude. Latitude is only valid from -90 to 90.