# Opening native Maps with Cordova on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, cordova

I'm trying to redirect user to the native Maps app on Android in Cordova. Here's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15746205/283863) that I found which is supposed to work on Android. However, when I use it in my Cordova app, ie,

```
location.href = "geo:" + lat +"," + lon;
```

it simply alerts,

> Application Error
>
> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME (geo:numbers here,number here)

What is causing this error and what would be a possible solution to this issue?

Comment: Please take a look at [this post](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/err-unknown-url-scheme-error-in-mailto-sms-and-tel-links) unless you already have. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Alp Mine is different because this link is not being opened in an in app browser.

Comment: So you haven't tried whitelisting `geo:`? The [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html) doesn't seem to make a distinction between accessing a URL from an in app browser or your app.

Comment: @not_a_bot I did whitelisted `geo:`.

Comment: can you provide the phonegap version you are using, and how did you whitelist the geo url?

Comment: @jcesarmobile I'm using Cordova 5.0.0 and I placed `<access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />` inside the `<widget>` tag in my config.xml.

Comment: Do you also have the Cordova whitelist [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) installed?

Comment: @not_a_bot It is installed. `cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"`

Comment: I even tried using `<allow-intent href="geo:*" />` with `window.open` but still no success.