# App to launch the Google Map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, google-maps, phonegap-plugins

I have implemented the cordova app using angular frame work.please guide me to launch the google map or map application by passing the longitude and langtitude.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the app open InAppBrowser:

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com/maps/place/' + latitude ',' + longtitude;
var inAppBrowser = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

If you want open native Google Map app:

```
window.location = 'comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic'
```

If you want open a Map app default on user phone:

```
window.location = 'geo:40.765819,-73.975866'
```

You can find more detail in there: [Android Phonegap - How to Open Native Google Maps Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745096/android-phonegap-how-to-open-native-google-maps-application)

And can find more url scheme of Google Map here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme#display_directions

Comment: very thanks and help full.. i have a doubt how to conditionally check the above  scenarios.. i want to open the  native app as default if it not there obviously i need to open in the  App brower..

2) other doubt is what is the difference between Google map App and Default Map app..

3)i need to pass the lat and long and open navigation view as default.

Comment: tell me about the default one ?? @SLyHuy

Comment: Some user don't like google map, they install another map app, like browser. We call it default map app.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with an specific intent like this:

```
        String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude,   longitude);
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but am looking for the cordova app code..