# Open native google map from "Phonegap" app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps

I am developing a phonegap app to find store location. I want to open native Google Map app with following direction interface -
[image]

I have the destination latitude and longitude and google map know my location. So I want to open google map app with direction. I have tried following -

```
var addressLongLat = $(this).data('lat')+','+$(this).data('long');
window.open('google.navigation:q='+addressLongLat);
```

Also try

```
var addressLongLat = $(this).data('lat')+','+$(this).data('long');
window.open('geo:q='+addressLongLat);
```

2nd one open Google Map but no direction and 1st one do nothing. I also try with anchor tag href but no luck. Webintent plugin also failed.Please anyone help me I am stuck for one week.

Answer (score 0):

> Turn by Turn Directions on Google Maps via PhoneGap

I tried this on my Chrome web browser on Android 4.4. And it worked perfectly. My code was:

```
window.open("google.navigation:q=29.589241,79.646666");
```

You could also add the mode of navigation by adding the "mode" parameter to the query.

I would also recommend reading up the following:

[Google Maps Intents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents)

[StackOverflow Question: Android Phonegap - How to Open Native Google Maps Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745096/android-phonegap-how-to-open-native-google-maps-application)

**If you are still having errors, you could share more of the code or the repository on Github.**